# Setup task scheduler to run actions but throws error on open

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, scheduled-tasks, command-line-arguments, class-library

I've setup a class library in VS and run functions using command line arguments.
I've built the project and copied the files in the 'debug' folder over to the server.
Copied over the database and changed the connection string to match.

On the server, I've setup a windows task scheduler to run the function every 15 mins:

In the 'create a basic task wizard' dialogue: start a program:
'Program/script:' chose the .exe file in the folder, and removed .config from the end of it.

'Added Argument': DownloadPOS

and 'start in':chose the same folder the project was in.

Problem being when the scheduler runs I get this error and have no idea why:
please advise

Comment: It fails to connect to your database. Check your connection-string.

Comment: thaks for the answer problem was in the connection string